# export data from access to excel 2007

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am new to vba coding and I am facing this problem.

I need to **transfer a table from Access DB to Excel**

But whenever i try to run the code
it gives an **error that says the table is not present in the DB**

My code:

```
 Sub hello()
 Call TransfertoExcel
 End Sub
 Public Function TransfertoExcel()
 On Error GoTo errorHandler

 Dim strTable As String
 Dim worksheetpath As String

 worksheetpath = "C:\Users\Desktop\test.xlsx"
 strTable = "TestTable"

 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acExport, _
 spreadsheettype:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
 TableName:=strTable, FileName:=worksheetpath, _
 hasfieldnames:=True

 errorHandlerexit:
 Exit Function

 errorHandler:

 MsgBox "Error no:" & Err.Number _
 & "; Description: " & Err.Description
 Resume errorHandlerexit

 End Function
```

Comment: It works for me. Check the spelling and that TestTable opens. Make sure you have `Option Explicit` at the top of the module

Comment: Is there any option we need to enable and the table name should be a table in access db ?

Comment: The table must be in the current database if you use that code. There are no options you need to enable.

Comment: Do i need to provide any references?

Comment: If you have not tampered with the default references and the database is not damaged, that code will run.